# Making a list with a number of entries equal to a variable

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list in python where the number of entries is dependent on a variable.

For example:

```
Var = 20
List = [random.randrange(-25,+26)]
```

I want the List to have 20 entries, based on the `Var` variable, each with the same initial value of `random.randrange(-25,+26)`.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the list:

```
List = [random.randrange(-25,+26)] * Var
```

This calls `random.randrange()` **once**, then references that same value 20 times to build a list of 20 entries.

If you wanted 20 *different* random values, use a list comprehension:

```
List = [random.randrange(-25,+26) for _ in range(Var)]
```